# jsonb – Spring search

Tags: spring, jpa, domain-driven-design, jsonb

How can I run the query

> `select * from companies where data->>'inn' like '%12%'`

using `org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification`?

```
class CompanySpecification : Specification<Company>{
    override fun toPredicate(root: Root<Company>, query:CriteriaQuery<*>, criteriaBuilder: CriteriaBuilder): Predicate? {
        return criteriaBuilder.like(root.get("data-->inn"), "%12%")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution

```
class CompanySpecification : Specification<Company> {

    override fun toPredicate(root: Root<Company>, query: CriteriaQuery<*>, builder: CriteriaBuilder): Predicate {
        return builder.like(builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String::class.java, root.get<String>("data"), builder.literal("inn")), "12%")
    }

}
```